# How to determine the order of bars in a matplotlib bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

Suppose we read some data into a pandas data frame:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv("data.csv", "\t")
```

The content looks like this:

[image]

And then define a function which should give us a horizontal bar chart, where the bar lengths represent values and the bars are labelled with the keys.

```
def barchart(data, labels):
    pos = arange(len(data))+.5    # the bar centers on the y axis
    barh(pos, data, align='center', height=0.25)
    yticks(pos, labels)
```

Then we call the plot function like this:

```
barchart(data1["val"], data1["key"])
```

which gives us the following plot:

[image]

Now, what determines the order of the bars?

Suppose we want the bars in a special order, say `[C, A, D, F, E, B]`, how can we enforce this?

Comment: just re-order your input.

Comment: @tcaswell How to reorder the input by the list `[C, A, D, F, E, B]` ?

Comment: @cls `barchart(data[['C', 'A', 'D', 'F', 'E', 'B']], labels)`

Comment: data[['C', 'A', 'D', 'F', 'E', 'B']] -- it is not going to work, this way you can select columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified original version of barchart. To specify order of bars I am using index set via ii column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def barchart(data, labels):
    pos = np.arange(len(data)) + 0.5  # the bar centers on the y axis
    plt.barh(pos, data.sort_index(), align='center', height=0.25)
    plt.yticks(pos, labels.sort_index())

data1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': list('ABCDE'), 'val': np.random.randn(5)})

new_keys = list('EDACB')
data1['ii'] = [new_keys.index(x) for x in data1.key]

data1 = data1.set_index('ii')
barchart(data1["val"], data1["key"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: How can I automatically generate the `data['ii‘]` column from the ordered list of keys?

Comment: i edit the answer to show how to generate data['ii'] column. Also take a look on bmu's answer below, it is really neat.

Answer (score 9):

If you directly read the key as the index with

```
In [12]: df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', '\t', index_col='key')

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
     val
key     
A    0.1
B    0.4
C    0.3
D    0.5
E    0.2
```

you can use `ix` to get the index in a different order and plot it using `df.plot`:

```
In [14]: df.ix[list('CADFEB')].plot(kind='barh')
Out[14]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x530fa90>
```

[image: barh_example.png]

(Note that F is not given in the data, but you gave it as an example)

Comment: **[Starting in 0.20.0, the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#IX%20indexer%20is%20deprecated)**

Instead use:
`df.reindex(labels).plot(kind='barh')`